# Invalid argument error in IE8 using KoGrid

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js, kogrid

I'm trying to use KoGrid but have learned I can't even get a very simple example to work without error in IE8.  Things are working fine in FF 9.0.1.

I've stripped down my original code to a very simple test that still shows the error:

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: {data: someList}"></div>
```

with javascript of:

```
var vm = {
    someList: ko.observableArray([{
        Name: "A Name",
        Synonym: "A Synonym"},
    {
        Name: "Another Name",
        Synonym: "Another Synonym"},
    {
        Name: "A third Name",
        Synonym: "A third Synonym"}])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

jsFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/SLMg7/6/

The error message from IE8 is:

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 2596
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.debug.js

I'm using knockout 2.2.0 and KoGrid 2.0.6 with jQuery 1.8.2.  I've used the debugger in VisStudio to break at the line, but it's on a finally line and I haven't yet been able to determine what is possibly wrong.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the new KoGrid. I've already filed a pull-request (https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/pull/151) on the KoGrid github page.

Comment: With the new [koGrid-2.0.7.debug.js](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/blob/master/koGrid-2.0.7.debug.js) version it's fixed and it should work fine in IE8. Voting to close...

Comment: Yes, it works now with that version.  Thank you!